# simulador javascript coste viaje con prompt alert funciones

Tags: javascript, funciones, variables, prompt

Estoy realizando un simulador calculando el costo total de productos y/o servicios seleccionados por el usuario, incorporando algoritmo condicional y
algoritmo con ciclos mediante `prompt` y `alert`, utilizando funciones para realizar esas operaciones.

Me está siendo imposible calcular el presupuesto final ya que todo el rato me dice que "noches" no está definido.

Creo que mi problema es que no sé almacenar el resultado ingresado en el navegador en una variable.

```js
let resultado1 = noches;
let resultado2 = cuidad;
let resultado3 = diasCoche;

function saludar(){
    alert(("Hola! Vamos a calcular tu próximo viaje :)"));
}


function hotel(){
    let noches = prompt("Ingresar número de noches siendo 4 el mínimo y 8 el máximo");
    switch(noches){
        case "4":
            alert("Tu número de noches son 4 a 350€")
            break;
        case "5":
            alert("Tu número de noches son 5 a 450€")
            break;
        case "6":
            alert("Tu número de noches son 6 a 550€")
            break;
        case "7":
            alert("Tu número de noches son 7 a 650€")
            break;
        case "8":
            alert("Tu número de noches son 8 a 750€")
            break;
            default:
                alert("Tu número de noches no es válido")
                break;
    }
    console.log(noches);
}


function vuelo(){
    let ciudad = prompt("Ingresa una ciudadad de las siguientes en la lista: Madrid, Paris, Roma, Copenhague");
    switch(ciudad){
        case "Madrid":
            alert("Tu vuelo a Madrid son 130€")
            break;
        case "Paris":
            alert("Tu vuelo a Paris son 230€")
            break;
        case "Roma":
            alert("Tu vuelo a Roma son 100€")
            break;
        case "Copenhague":
            alert("Tu vuelo a Copenhague son 300€")
            break;
        default:
            alert("No hay vuelos disponibles para esa ciudad")
            break;
    }
    console.log(ciudad);
}

function alquilerCoche(){
    let diasCoche = prompt("Ingresa los dias que alguilarás un coche. De 5 a 8 días");
    switch(diasCoche){
        case "5":
            alert("Tu coste de alquiler de coche para 5 días es de 400€")
            break;
        case "6":
            alert("Tu coste de alquiler de coche para 6 días es de 450€")
            break;
        case "7":
            alert("Tu coste de alquiler de coche para 7 días es de 500€")
            break;
        case "8":
            alert("Tu coste de alquiler de coche para 8 días es de 550€")
            break;
        case "0":
            alert("Tu coste de alquiler de coche para 0 días es de 0€")
            break;
            default:
                alert("No hay precios disponibles para esos días")
                break;
    }
    console.log(diasCoche);
}

function resultado(){
    let resultado1, resultado2, resultado3, resumen, suma;
    resumen=alert("Días de hotel: " + resultado1 + " ciudad destino: " + resultado2 + " días de coche alquilados: " + resultado3);
    suma=resultado1+resultado3;
    alert("tu presupuesto final es de: "+suma);
}


function ejecutarSimulador(){
    saludar();
    hotel();
    vuelo();
    alquilerCoche();
    resultado();
}
ejecutarSimulador();
```

Comment: cambia esto: let resultado1 = noches;
let resultado2 = cuidad;
let resultado3 = diasCoche; por esto: let resultado1 ="";
let resultado2 = "";
let resultado3 = "";

Comment: El problema acá es que estás definiendo variables antes de usarlas y en contextos inaccesibles, ya que `noches`, `ciudad` y `diasCoche` las defines dentro de funciones, pero entonces las llamas al principio del código.

Comment: Sugerencia: puedes reemplazar los switch por diccionarios haciendo el código más legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código se ejecuta linealmente, de arriba a abajo.

Las variables `noches`, `cuidad` y `diasCoche` no existen y tampoco están al alcance del código cuando las asignas a las variables `resultado`.

Así que inicialas en 0 y dales un nombre más descriptivo como `costoNoche`, `costoCiudad` y `costoCoche`.

Ahora, para que estas variables guarden sus respectivos costos, en cada función debes darle un valor diferente.

Además, las variables `noches`, `diasCoche` y `ciudad` solo existen como variables locales dentro de las funciones.

Para usarlas tanto fuera de las funciones como dentro debes ponerlas fuera.

Por cierto, las variables que declaras en la función `resultado` ocultan a las variables de afuera con el mismo nombre. Así que borralas.

Con estos cambios el código queda así:

```js
let costoNoches = 0
let costoCiudad = 0
let costoCoche = 0
let noches = ""
let diasCoche = ""
let ciudad = ""

function saludar(){
    alert(("Hola! Vamos a calcular tu próximo viaje :)"));
}

function hotel(){
    noches = prompt("Ingresar número de noches siendo 4 el mínimo y 8 el máximo");

    costoNoche = 0
    
    switch(noches){
        case "4":
            costoNoche = 350
            break;
        case "5":
            costoNoche = 450
            break;
        case "6":
            costoNoche = 550
            break;
        case "7":
            costoNoche = 650
            break;
        case "8":
            costoNoche = 750
            break;
    }
    
    if (costoNoche <= 0)
        alert("Tu número de noches no es válido")
    else
        alert(`Tu número de noches son ${noches} a ${costoNoche}€`)

    console.log(noches);
}

function vuelo(){
    ciudad = prompt("Ingresa una ciudadad de las siguientes en la lista: Madrid, Paris, Roma, Copenhague");

    costoCiudad = 0

    switch(ciudad){
        case "Madrid":
            costoCiudad = 130
            break;
        case "Paris":
            costoCiudad = 230
            break;
        case "Roma":
            costoCiudad = 100
            break;
        case "Copenhague":
            costoCiudad = 300
            break;
    }

    if (costoCiudad <= 0)
        alert("No hay vuelos disponibles para esa ciudad")
    else
        alert(`Tu vuelo a ${ciudad} son ${costoCiudad}€`)
    console.log(ciudad);
}

function alquilerCoche(){
    diasCoche = prompt("Ingresa los dias que alguilarás un coche. De 5 a 8 días");

    costoCoche = -1

    switch(diasCoche){
        case "5":
            costoCoche = 400
            break;
        case "6":
            costoCoche = 450
            break;
        case "7":
            costoCoche= 500
            break;
        case "8":
            costoCoche = 550
            break;
        case "0":
            costoCoche = 0
            break;
    }

    if (costoCoche < 0){
        alert("No hay precios disponibles para esos días")
        costoCoche = 0
    }
    else
        alert(`Tu coste de alquiler de coche para ${diasCoche} días es de ${costoCoche}`)

    console.log(diasCoche);
}

function resultado(){
    alert("Días de hotel: " + costoNoche + " ciudad destino: " + costoCiudad + " días de coche alquilados: " + costoNoche);
    suma = costoCiudad + costoCoche + costoNoche;
    alert("tu presupuesto final es de: " + suma);
}


function ejecutarSimulador(){
    saludar();
    hotel();
    vuelo();
    alquilerCoche();
    resultado();
}
ejecutarSimulador();
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tus comentarios he logrado entenderlo por fin!!

Comment: @hfriend1 de nada. Acepta la respuesta que más te haya ayudado dando clic en su tilde ✓

Answer (score 1):

La razón por la que obtienes el error es debido a que te encuentras inicializando las variables `resultado1`, `resultado2` y `resultado3` con variables que todavía no has declarado antes de ellas.

Corregí un poco tú código declarando las variables `resultado` globalmente, e inicializandolas en su respectivo prompt, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
//Declaramos las variables mas no inicializamos.
let resultado1
let resultado2
let resultado3

function saludar(){
    alert(("Hola! Vamos a calcular tu próximo viaje :)"));
}

function hotel(){
    let noches = prompt("Ingresar número de noches siendo 4 el mínimo y 8 el máximo");
    //Inicializamos 'resultado1'
    resultado1 = noches;
    switch(noches){
        case "4":
            alert("Tu número de noches son 4 a 350€")
            break;
        case "5":
            alert("Tu número de noches son 5 a 450€")
            break;
        case "6":
            alert("Tu número de noches son 6 a 550€")
            break;
        case "7":
            alert("Tu número de noches son 7 a 650€")
            break;
        case "8":
            alert("Tu número de noches son 8 a 750€")
            break;
            default:
                alert("Tu número de noches no es válido")
                break;
    }
    console.log(noches);
}


function vuelo(){
    let ciudad = prompt("Ingresa una ciudadad de las siguientes en la lista: Madrid, Paris, Roma, Copenhague");
  //Inicializamos 'resultado2'
    resultado2 = ciudad;
    switch(ciudad){
        case "Madrid":
            alert("Tu vuelo a Madrid son 130€")
            break;
        case "Paris":
            alert("Tu vuelo a Paris son 230€")
            break;
        case "Roma":
            alert("Tu vuelo a Roma son 100€")
            break;
        case "Copenhague":
            alert("Tu vuelo a Copenhague son 300€")
            break;
        default:
            alert("No hay vuelos disponibles para esa ciudad")
            break;
    }
    console.log(ciudad);
}

function alquilerCoche(){
    let diasCoche = prompt("Ingresa los dias que alguilarás un coche. De 5 a 8 días");
  //Inicializamos 'resultado3'
    resultado3 = diasCoche;
    switch(diasCoche){
        case "5":
            alert("Tu coste de alquiler de coche para 5 días es de 400€")
            break;
        case "6":
            alert("Tu coste de alquiler de coche para 6 días es de 450€")
            break;
        case "7":
            alert("Tu coste de alquiler de coche para 7 días es de 500€")
            break;
        case "8":
            alert("Tu coste de alquiler de coche para 8 días es de 550€")
            break;
        case "0":
            alert("Tu coste de alquiler de coche para 0 días es de 0€")
            break;
            default:
                alert("No hay precios disponibles para esos días")
                break;
    }
    console.log(diasCoche);
}

function resultado(){
    let resumen, suma; //No hay necesidad de volver a declarar las variables 'resultado', ya que estas se encuentran definidas globalmente
    resumen=alert("Días de hotel: " + resultado1 + " ciudad destino: " + resultado2 + " días de coche alquilados: " + resultado3);
    suma=resultado1+resultado3;
    alert("tu presupuesto final es de: "+suma);
}


function ejecutarSimulador(){
    saludar();
    hotel();
    vuelo();
    alquilerCoche();
    resultado();
}


ejecutarSimulador();
```

Comment: muchas gracias!! me ayudó mucho a comprender

Answer (score 1):

Tu código presenta varios errores.

El primero se presenta en secciones como esta:

```
let resultado1 = noches;

function hotel(){
    let noches = prompt("Ingresar número de noches siendo 4 el mínimo y 8 el máximo");
```

Donde intentas utilizar variables antes de definirlas.

El segundo error reside acá:

```
let resultado1 = noches;
let resultado2 = cuidad;
let resultado3 = diasCoche;

function resultado(){
    let resultado1, resultado2, resultado3, resumen, suma;
```

Donde redefines variables.

El tercero, es que:

```
let resultado1 = noches;
let resultado2 = cuidad;
let resultado3 = diasCoche;
```

`noches`, `ciudad` y `diasCoche` son variables locales, por lo que tu función `resultado` nunca podrá alcanzarlas. Tampoco las variables al inicio del código.

---

Te propongo este código, donde realicé algunos cambios para adaptarlo a lo que entiendo que buscas:

```js
let coste = 0;
let nochesHotel, ciudadDestino, diasCoche;

function saludar()
{
    alert("Hola! Vamos a calcular tu próximo viaje :)");
}

function hotel(){
    nochesHotel = prompt("Ingresar número de noches siendo 4 el mínimo y 8 el máximo");
    
    switch(nochesHotel){
        case "4":
            alert("Tu número de noches son 4 a 350€");
            coste += 350;
            break;
        case "5":
            alert("Tu número de noches son 5 a 450€");
            coste += 450;
            break;
        case "6":
            alert("Tu número de noches son 6 a 550€");
            coste += 550;
            break;
        case "7":
            alert("Tu número de noches son 7 a 650€");
            coste += 650;
            break;
        case "8":
            alert("Tu número de noches son 8 a 750€");
            coste += 750;
            break;
            default:
                alert("Tu número de noches no es válido");
                break;
    }
    console.log(nochesHotel);
}

function vuelo(){
    ciudadDestino = prompt("Ingresa una ciudad de las siguientes en la lista: Madrid, Paris, Roma, Copenhague");
    
    switch(ciudadDestino){
        case "Madrid":
            alert("Tu vuelo a Madrid son 130€");
            coste += 130;
            break;
        case "Paris":
            alert("Tu vuelo a Paris son 230€");
            coste += 230;
            break;
        case "Roma":
            alert("Tu vuelo a Roma son 100€");
            coste += 100;
            break;
        case "Copenhague":
            alert("Tu vuelo a Copenhague son 300€");
            coste += 300;
            break;
        default:
            alert("No hay vuelos disponibles para esa ciudad");
            break;
    }
    console.log(ciudadDestino);
}

function alquilerCoche(){
    diasCoche = prompt("Ingresa los dias que alguilarás un coche. De 5 a 8 días");
    switch(diasCoche){
        case "5":
            alert("Tu coste de alquiler de coche para 5 días es de 400€");
            coste += 400;
            break;
        case "6":
            alert("Tu coste de alquiler de coche para 6 días es de 450€");
            coste += 450;
            break;
        case "7":
            alert("Tu coste de alquiler de coche para 7 días es de 500€");
            coste += 500;
            break;
        case "8":
            alert("Tu coste de alquiler de coche para 8 días es de 550€");
            coste += 550;
            break;
        case "0":
            alert("Tu coste de alquiler de coche para 0 días es de 0€");
            break;
            default:
                alert("No hay precios disponibles para esos días");
                break;
    }
    console.log(diasCoche);
}

function resultado(){
    let cantNochesHotel = parseInt(nochesHotel);
    let cantDiasCoche   = parseInt(diasCoche);

    alert("Noches de hotel: " + cantNochesHotel + ", ciudad destino: " + ciudadDestino + ", días de coche alquilados: " + cantDiasCoche);
    alert("Tu presupuesto final es de: " + coste + "€");
}

function ejecutarSimulador()
{
    saludar();
    hotel();
    vuelo();
    alquilerCoche();
    resultado();
}

ejecutarSimulador();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! he logrado entenderlo con tus aclaraciones :))